# How to stop my transparency shader changing its visibility based on the observation angle

Tags: eevee-render-engine, toon-shading

I'm trying to add a semi transparent colour over an eye socket in my anime style model. I hocked up a transparent bsdf to a mix shader with a value connected to the fac input. In the preview render the sphere has a hole in the bottom and as a result causes my mesh to only display correctly at select angles. How can I fix this?

[image: Mesh with semi-transparent eye shadow, shader and shading options]

[image: different viewing angles resulting mesh not displaying]

[image: different viewing angles resulting mesh not displaying]

Comment: Probably, use alpha hash instead of alpha blend.  It's probably unsure of whether to draw this in front of or behind another alpha mesh.  But, possibly, it has to do with z-fighting between two meshes in the same or nearly the same position.

Comment: I already tried that, it greats this horrible grainy textured shadow, I need it clean. There's nothing near the shade mesh, other than at the edges in the socket rim.

Comment: You can use more samples to improve the look of alpha hashed.  Otherwise, you can figure out what alpha blend texture it's competing with, and change that other one.  Or, you can composite between multiple renders.

Comment: Compositing across multiple renders would be easier, I'm just not sure why its happening, the other shader is just a png with no transparency at all.

Comment: Sweet turned of the alpha on the other shader works perfectly. Its such a shame that's going to limit what I can do in future.